# Peculiar Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I came up with this idea recently and I want to go deeper in this, but it has been difficult to me. Hope someone can help me on this.

Suppose I have a matrix of order $(n^2-1)\times (n^2-1)$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_{n^2-1}$. I can write its characteristic polynomial as $$p(z) = a_{n^2-1}z^{n^2-1}+a_{n^2-2}z^{n^2-2}+\ldots+a_1z + a_0.$$

After this, we can construct the $n\times n$ matrix given by
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
a_0 & a_1 & \ldots & a_{n-1}\\
a_n & a_{n+1} & \ldots & a_{2n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n^2-n} & a_{n^2-n+1} & \ldots & a_{n^2-1}
 \end{pmatrix}$$

My question is: what can we say about the matrix $M$?

I know this question is a little vague, I'm just starting to explore this matrix. Thus, any interesting result is very welcome.

Comment: Any $n\times n$ matrix whose $(n,n)$th entry is 1 arises this way. You can work-backwards construct an $(n^2-1)\times (n^2-1)$ matrix having this as characteristic polynomial (its companion matrix).

Comment: It follows from @PVanchinathan's comment that you cannot say anything about your matrix!

Comment: Are you talking about the $(n^2-1)\times (n^2-1)$ matrix? Im not interested in that one, Im interested on the latter matrix.

Comment: Im saying this because looks like you all are talking about the $(n^2−1)\times(n^2−1)$ companion matrix of the given characteristic polynomial. I dont care about this matrix, I care about the $n\times n$ defined with the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, just as I defined above. I can't see how this matrix has anything to do with the companion matrix, starting with its order, which is different, and the places where the coefficients are allocated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first part, since you have distinct $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{n^2-1}$ (was this the intention?) you know that your matrix is diagonalizable.

From the characteristic polynomial you know that the trace of your matrix is $-a_{n^2-2}/a_{n^2-1}$ (and $a_{n^2-1}$ must be nonzero, else you don't have an $n^2-1 \times n^2-1$ matrix).

Also from the characteristic polynomial the determinant of your matrix is $(-1)^{n^2-1}a_0/a_{n^2-1}$.

---

ok, I added this part later, once I understood that your main interest is in the matrix $M$ of coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, as defined by you above. Well from the above the only thing you can really say is that $a_{n^2-1}$ is nonzero. So really you have the set \begin{equation} \left \{ (m_{ij}) \in \mathbb{F}_{n \times n}:m_{nn}\neq0\right \}.\end{equation} In fact we could restrict it a little further by noticing that we always have $a_{n^2-1}=1$ since the characteristic polynomial is always monic. So then we have the set \begin{equation} \left \{ (m_{ij}) \in \mathbb{F}_{n \times n}:m_{nn}=1\right \}.\end{equation}

Comment: $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_{n^2-1}$ are not necessarily distinct.

Comment: ok well, then you know that you can construct at least one matrix with all the given requirements.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial belongs to the first matrix, the $(n^2-1)\times (n^2-1)$ matrix, Im not looking to this matrix. I want to know about properties of the second matrix, Its already constructed.

Comment: Im saying this because looks like you all are talking about the $(n^2-1)\times(n^2-1)$ companion matrix of the given characteristic polynomial. I dont care about this matrix, I care about the $n\times n$ defined with the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, just as I defined above. I can't see how this matrix has anything to do with the companion matrix, starting with its order, which is different, and the places where the coefficients are allocated.

Thanks.

Comment: ah ok - I get it now...it really comes down to how much you can say about each of the $a_i$, and with my knowledge regarding characteristic polynomials what I have presented above is all you can say. You have $a_{n^2-1}$ is nonzero, and some relations to the trace and determinant of the original matrix. The only restriction is basically that $a_{n^2-1}$ is nonzero, each of the other $a_i$ can be any number from the field of the original matrix. So you have the set of all $n \times n$ matrices with a nonzero $(n,n)$ entry.